# Values in multiple columns and rows and mark as "X"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns, vlookup, vba

I have a table in worksheet 1 which contains values in 2 columns (E & F). In worksheet 2 I need to indicate on a table with an "X" if my values are found.

The Logic:

---

- IF B7 (Sheet 2) EXISTS in column F:F (Sheet 1) AND
- IF C5 (Sheet 2) EXISTS in column E:E (Sheet 1)
- Where both (B7 & C5) EXISTS on same ROW (Sheet 1)
- Mark the current cell (C7) (Sheet 2) as "X" if not blank " ".

---

I can't seem to solve this with the current function please help.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$5, Sheet1!E:E)), (ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B7, Sheet1!F:F)))), "X", "")
```

I can't seem to solve how I can this to be marked as "X".

In the images i want to be able to mark in Sheet 2 "x" where Value 1 and Value 2 exist on the same row on sheet 2 (row 5 in columns E & F)

Both C7 & C9 should have an “X” in the following example.

Sheet 1

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: how about vlookup function?

Comment: I tried using multiple different methods, I can’t get the logic of if they both are on same row then mark as true (or X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use COUNTIFS rather than SEARCH. SEARCH is for finding the position of a match for a substring (like "alu") in a string (like "Value"). Although it can be used with a list of strings in an array formula, this is not the easiest way to do it. COUNTIFS finds the number of matches for one or more conditions in the same row in one or more ranges which is what you want to do here. The formula is

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E:E,$C$5,Sheet1!F:F,$B7),"x","")
```

If you wanted to find matches for Value 1.1 and Value 1.2 as well as Value 1, you could use a wildcard

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E:E,$C$5&"*",Sheet1!F:F,$B7),"x","")
```

[image]